# SymPy.jl strange report of eigenvalues compared with using SymPy in python

Tags: julia, sympy

SymPy in Python:

```
>>> M = Matrix([[-4, sqrt(2)], [sqrt(2), -5]])
>>> M
Matrix([
[     -4, sqrt(2)],
[sqrt(2),      -5]])
>>> dict_eig = M.eigenvals()
>>> dict_eig
{-6: 1, -3: 1}
```

SymPy.jl (Julia):

```
julia> M = sympy.Matrix([[-4, sqrt(2)], [sqrt(2), -5]])
2×2 Array{Sym,2}:
 -4.00000000000000   1.41421356237310
  1.41421356237310  -5.00000000000000

julia> dict_eig = M.eigenvals()
Dict{Any,Any} with 2 entries:
  -9/2 - sqrt(225000000000001400410360361)/10000000000000 => 1
  -9/2 + sqrt(225000000000001400410360361)/10000000000000 => 1
```

The result is actually correct but pretty weird.. why is that and how can I get the form reported in Python ?

Comment: Do you know whether you are using the same version of SymPy in both cases?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin: yes, I use the same python environment for python / pycall in Julia (python3, sympy v. 1.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implicitly using sympy's sqrt implementation in the python version. If you call sympy's sqrt directly you'll get equivalent results.

```
julia> M = [[-4 sympy.sqrt(2)]; [sympy.sqrt(2) -5]]
2×2 Array{Sym,2}:
      -4  sqrt(2)
 sqrt(2)       -5

julia> M.eigenvals()
Dict{Any,Any} with 2 entries:
  -3 => 1
  -6 => 1
```